# how to drag and drop the folder into the terminal window in snow leopard mac

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

Am trying to install Phonegap 2.0 in Mac OS X 10.6.8. Am following the steps from this link:

```
 "http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts"
```

Here the document mentioned to drag and drop the "bin" folder on "Terminal Window" placed in "Dock". 
 If we done this Terminal Window open with like this below Screen Short.

[image]

I have tried to do this like drag and drop the bin folder to Terminal Window in Dock. But, this is not happening. When i try to drag and drop the bin folder to Terminal App it is not opening. Can anyone please help me to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature where you drag a folder onto the Terminal icon in the dock requires MacOS 10.7 or later.

However, it's just a shortcut. You can accomplish the same thing by:

1. Open a new terminal window.
2. Type `cd` followed by a space — don't press return yet!
3. Drag the folder into the terminal window
4. Press return

Answer (score 0):

Drug it right on the open Terminal window where you see the text, this will add the path to the dragged file/folder right to the cursor position.

Comment: It is showing only path.  like this: "unknownc82a143f73f2:~ creagx$ /Users/creagx/Desktop/PhonegapNew/bin". Sorry i don't want this. I want the folder name. I had mention in Screen Short in above question.

Comment: I want like this: (e.x) unknownc82a143f73f2:~ bin CompanyName$.